# Silverlight/WPF - Can you have a different ItemTemplate depending on a base type of the item?

Tags: silverlight, templates

I am binding an ObservableCollection to a ListBox in Silverlight.  The list can contain multiple Person or Vehicle objects which both derive from DomainObject.  I would like to be able to have a different template for Person and Vehicle, but show them both in the same list.  What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DataTemplateSelector is not available in silverlight but there are a few resources around showing examples of how to implement it in a control.

1. [Resource 1](http://www.tozon.info/blog/post/2009/03/15/Dynamic-Data-Forms-for-Silverlight-with-a-Data-Template-Selector-Control.aspx)
2. [Resource 2](http://silverlight.net/forums/t/78702.aspx)